# Why does this array initialisation cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, g++

I'm declaring an array of uint8_t with 10 milion elements. It should fit in memory and under all indexing limits. I'm compiling using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4 via Geany.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<stdint.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint8_t in[10000000];
    printf("%li", sizeof(in));
}
```

Comment: 1) It's not C. 2) You have a stack overflow. 3) You don't have a `return` statement.

Comment: There's a limit on the size of local variables in a function, you're going beyond it.

Comment: To state the maybe obvious: local variables are allocated on the stack. Perfect fit to the name of this site ...